# Re-enable visual styles in designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I had a warning of Visual Studio stating something about it's going to disable the visual styles because of performance issues.
Because of this I have no styles in my Visual Studio. 
I reset al settings but the issue remain.
When loading another Solution everything works as expected, so it's Solution/Project based.

How do I re-enable this?
In Visual Studio:
[image: In Visual Studio]
In Runtime:
[image: Runtime]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked in the solution in TFS.
Deleted my files locally and got the latest version back from TFS and everything worked again.
Another 3h wasted.

I had the same issue again today, and I found right the solution to the problem:
[image: Enable Project Code]